# What's the different between 'new' and not 'new' instance when using RequireJs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm wondering what's the different between new module and not new module when using RequireJs. What's the different? and which one should I use. For example I have this module

```
define('somemodule', [], function() {
   var module = function() {
       var method = function() {
           return "something";
       }

       return {
           method : method
       };
   };
   return module;
});

// Use the module (import)
require(['somemodule'], function(somemodule){
    console.log(new somemodule().method());
    console.log(somemodule().method());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/fpT9K/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it *does not* matter, if you call `somemodule` with or without `new`!

**Why?**

Because your `contructor` returns a new object and does not make use of `this`.

But if we translate your example as followed..

```
var module = function() {
    var method = function() {
        return "something";
    }

    this.method = method;
};
```

.. it works the same. Now if you call `module` with `new`, the tiny `this` refers to a *new* scope. Because `new` creates a new scope for your constructor.

Because of that you can use your module like this:

```
var myInstance = new module();
myInstance.method(); // will output "something"
```

But now, if you call `module` without `new`, the `this` will refer to the global scope, which is the `window` object in a browser.

```
var myInstance = module();
myInstance.method(); // will cause an error
method(); // will output "something" which is not what you wanted.
```

**So?**

The `new` prefix makes sure, your module gets it's own scope. But as I said, your example with `module` returning an object and *not using `this`*, it does'nt matter either you use `new` or not.

**How to prevent functions from being called without new?**

Stick to widely used naming conventions: constructors are Capitalized.

And in bigger projects you should test if the `constructor` function is called with `new`:

```
var Module = function() {
    // simply check if "this" is an instance of "module"
    if (! (this instanceof Module)) {
        // and if not, call "module" again, with the "new" prefix
        return new Module();
    }

    var method = function() {
        return "something";
    }

    this.method = method;
};
```

Comment: Constructor functions *can* return something, and often do.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with any other function, calling via `new` instantiates a new object for the value of `this` in the function. When you call it without `new`, as in the second call, the value of `this` will be that object returned from the main module function.

As to which you should use, that depends on what "method" expects to be able to do with `this`. It might not matter at all, or it might matter a lot; it depends on the actual code and the design of your system.

Comment: Can you please explain the situation where not using 'new' is a bad?

Comment: @toy it's not necessarily bad; it may in fact be the correct thing to do. There's really nothing special about modules here; this is a matter of basic JavaScript functionality and the way that `new` *always* works.